# How to automatically open pdf when user open specific page?

Tags: wordpress

What im trying to do is when user enter specific page to automatically open pdf instead that page? How can i achive that?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test, but try adding this to the function.php in your theme:

```
add_action('init', 'show_pdf');

function show_pdf() {
    if (is_page($page_id)) {
        header('Content-type:application/pdf');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Expires: 0');
        readfile($file_path);
        exit;
    }
}
```

and replace $page_id with the ID of the page and $file_path with the local path to the PDF file.